# Recommendation system with large amount of data

Tags: recommendation-engine, sparse-matrix, collaborative-filtering

I'm implementing a movie recommendation system with real user data. I planned to take the collaborative filtering method. However, this kind of methods usually involve a huge matrix storing the users their rated movies. Since I have more than ten thousand movies and hundred thousand users. It is impossible for me to create such a huge sparse matrix. I wonder how everyone implement collaborative filtering with such a large amount of data? Thanks!

Comment: What's the issue with a huge *sparse* matrix? that ought to be just fine.

Comment: The matrix is so huge that I can't create it in my matlab. Could it be solved using other languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend distributed computing frameworks to you, but, I think is still of a scale that you can easily handle it on one machine.

[Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org) contains the Taste collaborative filtering library, which was designed to scale on one machine. A model of -- what, 10M data points? -- should fit in memory with a healthy heap size. Look at things like `GenericItemBasedRecommender` and `FileDataModel`.

(Mahout also has distributed implementations based on Hadoop, but I don't think you need this yet.)

I'm the author of that, but have since moved on to commercialize large-scale recommenders as [Myrrix](http://myrrix.com). It also contains a stand-alone single machine version, which is free and [open source](http://myrrix.com/download/). It also will easily handle this amount of data on one machine. For example, this is a smaller data set than what's used in [this example](http://myrrix.com/example-performance/). Myrrix also has a distributed implementation.

There are other fast *distributed* implementations beyond the above, like [GraphLab](http://graphlab.org/). Other non-distributed frameworks are also probably fast enough, like [MyMediaLite](http://mymedialite.net/).

I would suggest just using one of these, or if you really are just wondering "how" it happens, check into the source code and look at the data representation.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the matrix form to store my data. Instead, I use C++ and build some structs like User, Rating, Item which contain the variables and arrays that I need. This may increase the complexity of algorithm but it can save the memory efficiently.